# Manually calculate the confidence intervals of estimated values for a multiple regression model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

How can one calculate the upper and lower bounds of estimates (fitted values) from a multiple regression manually? I know how to do that in simple linear regression as demonstrated below, but I am lost on how to do it in case of multiple variables with factors.

```
x <- rnorm(150); y <- rnorm(length(x)); z <- rep(c("a","b","c"), length=length(x)) 
# for simple linear regression confidence intervals are calculated as follows. 
fit<-lm(y~x)
summary(fit)
# Automatic calculation 
AutoConfidence <- data.frame(predict(fit, interval="confidence"))
# Manual calculation of confidence interval 
Estimate <- predict(fit)
ManualUpperLimit <- Estimate + 1.978 * summary(fit)$sigma * sqrt(1/length(x) + (x-mean(x))^2 / sum((x-mean(x))^2))
ManualLowerLimit <- Estimate - 1.978 * summary(fit)$sigma * sqrt(1/length(x) + (x-mean(x))^2 / sum((x-mean(x))^2))
```

So, how can I manually compute the CI of the estimates (fitted values) for the following multiple regression model?

```
fit2 <- lm(y~x+z)
```

Comment: You can use `confint(fit2)` to get the values from R.  I don't how exactly they are computed, but `?confint` and `confint.lm` may provide answers.